# PowerShell XML to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, powershell

I have composed a very simple code to pass my XML export to a SQL Server database. Everything works and the data appears in the table as it should.

However when I tested with one single record from the list (around 120k of them) and it took me around 20sec. It must be a better way to pass information across. I attached the code below for people who know how to do it. I guess my code is very simple and works with the principles and not necessary the right way.

Since I produce an XML every day it is really important that I speed this procedure up. As I have never done it before and eager to learn any comments/links are very welcome. Thank you for anyone's time in advance.

```
$sqlserver="test"
$db="test"
$table="dbo.test"
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = "Server=$sqlserver; Database=$db; Integrated Security = True;"
$conn.Open()


$cmd=$conn.CreateCommand()
[xml]$xmllog="<logroot>$(get-content("I:\somefile.xml"))</logroot>"
$idevent=$xmllog.logroot.Event.system.eventid[0]
$levelcode=$xmllog.logroot.Event.system.level[0]
$times=$xmllog.logroot.Event.system.timecreated.systemtime[0]
$computers=$xmllog.logroot.Event.system.computer[0]
$subUser=$xmllog.logroot.Event.selectsinglenode("//*[@Name='SubjectUserName']")[0].'#text'
$subdomain=$xmllog.logroot.Event.selectsinglenode("//*[@Name='SubjectDomainName']")[0].'#text'
$targUser=$xmllog.logroot.Event.selectsinglenode("//*[@Name='TargetUserName']")[0].'#text'
$targetDom=$xmllog.logroot.Event.selectsinglenode("//*[@Name='TargetDomainName']")[0].'#text'
$logontypes=$xmllog.logroot.Event.selectsinglenode("//*[@Name='LogonType']")[0].'#text'
$logonproc=$xmllog.logroot.Event.selectsinglenode("//*[@Name='LogonProcessName']")[0].'#text'
$workstation=$xmllog.logroot.Event.selectsinglenode("//*[@Name='WorkstationName']")[0].'#text'
$ipaddress=$xmllog.logroot.Event.selectsinglenode("//*[@Name='IpAddress']")[0].'#text'

$cmd.CommandText="insert dbo.test  values (1, '$idevent', '$levelcode', '$times','$computers', '$subUser', '$subdomain','$targUser', '$targetDom', '$logontypes', '$logonproc', '$workstation','$ipaddress')"

$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$conn.Close()
```

Comment: Is it the `INSERT` that's taking 20 seconds or the xml file parsing? Are you saying you have 120K separate records in the single xml file? Perhaps an xml snippet will help.

Comment: The file load takes 5 sec, the selectsinglenodes are eacha  few secs the INSERT is fairly fast

Comment: Can you add a snippet of the xml? It may be possible to reduce the amount of xml parsing and improve performance.

Comment: could you pleas give me a link or a quick guide how to? thank you

Comment: I can't point you to a link because I don't know the actual underlying xml structure, which I can't glean due to the xpath wildcard expressions. Assume the xml is well-structured, the general approach I would use is to iterate over the collection of a specific node type and then use relative DOM methods to get data for the SQL row. I expect that would be faster than executing selectsinglenode many times per record.

Comment: One option may be to transform the XML using XSLT to a format understood by BCP (https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1060/bcp-xml-format-files-with-sql-server-2005/).

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the properties and executing `SelectSingleNode()` on every 120k nodes each time you set a variable, and then you just keep the first result for each. What you should do is pick the first event-node and run `SelectSingleNode()` etc. on that.

Ex.

```
$event = $xmllog.logroot.Event[0]

    $idevent=$event.system.eventid
    $levelcode=$event.system.level
    $times=$event.system.timecreated.systemtime
    $computers=$event.system.computer
    $subUser=$event.selectsinglenode("//*[@Name='SubjectUserName']").'#text'
    #etc...
```

I'm not sure what your xml-looks like, but to test I used this:

```
$xmllog = [xml]@"
<logroot>
    <Event>
        <System>
            <Eventid>1</Eventid>
            <Level>3</Level>
            <Computer>Computer1</Computer>
            <Timecreated systemtime="10:24" />
            <Attribute Name="SubjectUserName">User1</Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="SubjectDomainName">DomainA</Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="TargetUserName">User11</Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="TargetDomainName">DomainB</Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="LogonType">Windows</Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="LogonProcessName">Winlogon.exe</Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="WorkstationName">Computer1</Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="IpAddress">192.168.1.10</Attribute>
        </System>
    </Event>
        <Event>
        <System>
            <Eventid>1</Eventid>
            <Level>3</Level>
            <Computer>Computer2</Computer>
            <Timecreated systemtime="10:24" />
            <Attribute Name="SubjectUserName">User2</Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="SubjectDomainName">DomainA</Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="TargetUserName">User21</Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="TargetDomainName">DomainB</Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="LogonType">Windows</Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="LogonProcessName">Winlogon.exe</Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="WorkstationName">Computer2</Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="IpAddress">192.168.1.11</Attribute>
        </System>
    </Event>
</logroot>
"@
```

To further speed it up when processing all events, you could try something like this to batch import using a single INSERT-statement. I'm not sure what your batch size limit is. If the query gets to big, you can split it up for each ex. each 10k row.

```
$sqlserver="test"
$db="test"
$table="dbo.test"
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = "Server=$sqlserver; Database=$db; Integrated Security = True;"
$conn.Open()

$cmd=$conn.CreateCommand()
[xml]$xmllog="<logroot>$(get-content("I:\somefile.xml"))</logroot>"

$rows = @()

foreach ($event in $xmllog.logroot.Event) {

    $idevent=$event.system.eventid
    $levelcode=$event.system.level
    $times=$event.system.timecreated.systemtime
    $computers=$event.system.computer
    $subUser=$event.selectsinglenode("//*[@Name='SubjectUserName']").'#text'
    $subdomain=$event.selectsinglenode("//*[@Name='SubjectDomainName']").'#text'
    $targUser=$event.selectsinglenode("//*[@Name='TargetUserName']").'#text'
    $targetDom=$event.selectsinglenode("//*[@Name='TargetDomainName']").'#text'
    $logontypes=$event.selectsinglenode("//*[@Name='LogonType']").'#text'
    $logonproc=$event.selectsinglenode("//*[@Name='LogonProcessName']").'#text'
    $workstation=$event.selectsinglenode("//*[@Name='WorkstationName']").'#text'
    $ipaddress=$event.selectsinglenode("//*[@Name='IpAddress']").'#text'

    $rows += "(1, '$idevent', '$levelcode', '$times','$computers', '$subUser', '$subdomain','$targUser', '$targetDom', '$logontypes', '$logonproc', '$workstation','$ipaddress')"
}

#Combine value-strings
$values = $rows -join ", " 
$cmd.CommandText = "insert into $table values $values;"

$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$conn.Close()
```

`CommandText` would be like this with the sample xml above:

```
"insert into dbo.test values (1, '1', '3', '10:24','Computer1', 'User1', 'DomainA','User11', 'DomainB', 'Windows', 'Winlogon.exe', 'Computer1','192.168.1.10'), (1, '1', '3', '10:24','Computer2', 'User1', 'DomainA','User11', 'DomainB', 'Windows', 'Winlogon.exe', 'Computer1','192.168.1.10');"
```

**Warning**: Consider using parameterized queries unless you really trust the input data. This query is prone to sql injection.

Comment: It will be faster to load the data into a DataTable and use SqlBulkCopy rather than individual inserts. SqlBulkCopy is inherently parameterized and optimized for loading large batches of rows. I'd expect 120K rows inserted to take seconds with SqlBulkCopy rather than minutes with separate inserts.